# How to post array of values to webapi?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am a newbie to C# am trying to post an array of values to a webapi POST method. Not sure how to go about this. This is what I have so far:

In the controller class:

```
namespace SATLyncWebService.Controllers
{
    [RoutePrefix("lync")]
    public class LyncController : ApiController
    {

        // POST: lync/search/
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("search")]

        public void Post([FromBody]string value)
        {
            log.Info(value.ToString());
        }
    }
```

I get a NullReferenceException on the value field when I send a POST message as follows:

```
POST http://localhost:55129/lync/search
Application/json

["user1",
 "user2 "
]
```

Thoughts?

Comment: and why would someone downvote this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's because your signature is taking a single string as opposed to an IEnumerable (or any other sort of collection - List, []...) therefore webapi can't deserialize into that type

Comment: You can then accept that as an answer. Glad it worked!